# Issue in QLineEdit with title()?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, title, qlineedit

In my Programme. use two QLineEdit. First one is normal and second one is **titled Line edit**. First one/normal QLineEidt  works smoothly,   But In second textbox(QLineEdit), I **cannot insert a text** at begging or any where at a time.

for example : I entered a text "Python". Now I add "Hello" to begging of the text ("Hello Python"). If I try to type "Hello", I can insert only one word at a time, (press home key, type word "H",after that cursor jumps to end, once again we move cursor to second position and enter a word "O", Once we enter word "O" cursor jumps to end of the text and so on). I want to type(insert) a text at a stretch.

How to OverCome?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont

class Lineedit_title(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(100,100,500,500)

        self.textbox1 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.textbox1.setGeometry(50,50,200,50)
        self.textbox1.setFont(QFont("Caliber", 15, QFont.Bold))

        self.textbox2 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.textbox2.setGeometry(50,140,200,50)
        self.textbox2.setFont(QFont("Caliber",15,QFont.Bold))
        self.textbox2.textChanged.connect(self.textbox_textchange)

    def textbox_textchange(self,txt):
        self.textbox2.setText(txt.title())

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Lineedit_title()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you use `setText()` the cursor position is set at the end of the text, in this case the cursor position must be saved and restored before and after `setText()`, respectively:

```
def textbox_textchange(self, txt):
    position = self.textbox2.cursorPosition()
    self.textbox2.setText(txt.title())
    self.textbox2.setCursorPosition(position)
```

A more elegant solution is to use a custom validator:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLineEdit, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QValidator


class TitleValidator(QValidator):
    def validate(self, text, pos):
        return QValidator.Acceptable, text.title(), pos


class Lineedit_title(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 500)

        self.textbox1 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.textbox1.setGeometry(50, 50, 200, 50)
        self.textbox1.setFont(QFont("Caliber", 15, QFont.Bold))

        self.textbox2 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.textbox2.setGeometry(50, 140, 200, 50)
        self.textbox2.setFont(QFont("Caliber", 15, QFont.Bold))

        validator = TitleValidator(self.textbox2)
        self.textbox2.setValidator(validator)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Lineedit_title()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Super.  I got a clear way. Thankyou very much for your proper guide.